# Equivalency of two definitions for statistical distance

Tags: statistics, cryptography

Suppose **X** and **Y** are two distributions on finite discrete *sample space* **S** and we define *statistical distance* as fallow :
$$\Delta(X,Y)=1/2 * \sum_{w\in S} |Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w)|$$ 
and i wanna proof the upper definition is equivalent to : 
$$sup_{A\subseteq S}|Pr(X\in A) - Pr(Y\in A)|$$

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about what to try to solve this?  Have you tried considering a simple case (eg S has only 3 elements)?  Also, I wonder if there is any mileage in splitting S into those w where P(X=w) > P(Y=w) and those w where the opposite is true.  I don't know how to solve this (yet!) but those are the ideas I'm  going to think about...

PS Why is this tagged "calculus"?

Answer (score 3):

Define $S_+ = \{w\in S:Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w)>0\}$ and $S_- = S_+^c$.

Note that $\sum_{w\in S_+} Pr(X=w) = 1-\sum_{w\in S_-} Pr(X=w)$ and similarly for $Pr(Y=w)$.

Also:
for $w\in S_+, |Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w)| =Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w) $;
for $w\in S_-, |Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w)| =-Pr(X=w)+Pr(Y=w) $

Putting all the above together, we can show $$ \Delta(X,Y)=\sum_{w\in S_+} (Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w))$$

Now consider $d(A) = |Pr(X\in A) - Pr(Y\in A)|$:

$$d(S_+) = \sum_{w\in S_+} (Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w))$$
$$d(S_-) = -\sum_{w\in S_-} (Pr(X=w)-Pr(Y=w))$$
But because $\sum_{w\in S_+} Pr(X=w) = 1-\sum_{w\in S_-} Pr(X=w)$, then $d(S_+) = d(S_-)$ and more importantly $d(S_+) = \Delta(X,Y)$.

Therefore, all that remains to prove is that for any $A\subseteq S$, $d(A) \le d(S_+)$ which will then imply that $sup_{A\subseteq S}[d(A)] = d(S_+) = \Delta(X,Y)$ which is the required result.

To establish $d(A) \le d(S_+)$, consider what happens to $d(A)$ if $A \subseteq S_+$ and you remove or add another element of $S_+$.  You can show $d(A)$ will only increase if you add elements of $S_+$, so this shows $S_+$ maximises $d(A)$.  If you start adding elements of $S_-$ then $d(A)$ decreases.